# MySQL get value

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, phpmyadmin, mysql-connector

Since yesterday I am trying to get this value (see image), I have tried to use "mysqlreader, executescalar and more", but I cannot get the number of lines.

What I want to do is this:
If the result is 0 it does nothing, if equal to 1 it must show an image, if greater than 1 it must show another image

[image: phpmyadmin count]

```
private void patient()
{
    if (OpenEventMissionData.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in OpenEventMissionData.Rows)
        {
            string idevent = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM patient INNER JOIN event WHERE patient.ID_EVENT = " + "'" + idevent + "'" + "AND evento.EVENT_OPEN = 1;";

            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {   
                DataGridViewButtonColumn patient = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
                OpenEventMissionData.Columns.Add(new PatientColumn());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding the code that told me @oldDog, but the result is always 6

**NEW EDIT:**

In fact 6 lines appear.

[image: phpmyadmin]

Comment: Please explain what problem you're experiencing. It's currently unclear how your code behaves differently from your expectation. Are you getting an exception? Or perhaps a different result?

Comment: the result is different via "System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show (test);" it appears to me three times, with the following messages:
1) 6 2) 0 3) 0

Comment: How does your data look? What do you expect should happen? (remember you're in a `foreach` loop so it's logical you get more results) Have you debugged to verify that your `sql` query is correct?

Comment: Side notes: you must *not* inject data into your queries, as it's **dangerous**. Use parameters instead. Also need `using` to dispose objects properly

Comment: @Xerillio it should display how many patients have associated an event code, depending on the number show a button within a datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is you are using HasRows. Since you are doing SELECT COUNT(*) you will always have one row which will contain the count, even if the count is zero. Instead you could use:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]) > 0)
```

Comment: I tried as you told me, but going to check later through a message box, the number 6 appears (I updated the post to add the modified code)

Comment: 6 should be your count then. I would put a breakpoint in your code on the line assigning the value to sql, copy the sql command to PHPMyAdmin and remove the COUNT function, use just SELECT *, then see what values you are getting.

Comment: i added a photo of the phpmyadmin result

Comment: I understand the problem, is now I feel stupid.
This works "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE patient.EVENT_ID = 220000001", I believe the problem is INNER JOIN which added the event table